# Can I use CSS file extension instead of cshtml for the Razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

The idea is that I'm building a CSS file generating service, it's working just fine. But I need the view file extension to be CSS instead of cshtml so I take advantage of the visual studio intellisense.

Any ideas?

Comment: VS IntelliSense will not combine CSS and Razor unless you write a VS addin.  I believe someone did so.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own ViewEngine which inherits from the Razor View Engine. There you'll need to set the [FileExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.virtualpathproviderviewengine.fileextensions%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) property to include css. [Here](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Creating_a_Custom_View_Engine_in_ASPNET_MVC.aspx) is a guide to creating it. The other option is to find the Razor View Engine from the View Engines list and try setting it there.

Comment: Actually I was looking for something like this .. but it did not work for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110970/can-i-serve-html-files-using-razor-as-if-they-were-cshtml-files-without-changi

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can possibly think this setup a custom HTTP handler; there you can give it an explicit name, and try giving it a file extension of CSS... Not 100% sure it will work, but you could give it a shot; though you would need to move the code to a class implementing `IHttpHandler`.

However, I don't think either way will work with Visual Studio Intellisense.  If you want intellisense, add the CSS to the markup, then remove it programmatically at runtime.  This is one possible way to work around it.