# How to register additional file extension as MVC Razor template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I would like to register an additional extension (e.g. .template) as an MVC Razor template, so I get code completion and syntax highlighting for Razor inside files with the new extension.

I've tried adding a build provider in the web.config

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" >
  <buildProviders>
    <add extension=".template" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider, System.Web.WebPages.Razor"/>
  </buildProviders>
</compilation>
```

but it's not recognized as Razor template.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, you're going in the right direction. Take a look at this post, it explains the rest: [Can I serve .html files using Razor as if they were .cshtml files without changing the extension of all my pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110970/can-i-serve-html-files-using-razor-as-if-they-were-cshtml-files-without-changi)

Comment: odd, I tried all of that, but still not recognized as a razor file