# How to add another file extension to Razor ViewEngine, e.g. *.html

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want use *.html to instead *.cshtml in asp.net mvc.

Is there any way to solve? what do i do?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? The razor view is rendered into a html by the framework, but you cannot use the razor view directly like 'http://yoursite/yourrazorview.cshtml'.

Comment: You will need to [write your own view engine](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/294297/Creating-your-own-MVC-View-Engine-into-MVC-Applica).

Comment: You can also just write html code in the cshtml file. There is no requirement to have c# or Razor code in the file.

Comment: Asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110970/can-i-serve-html-files-using-razor-as-if-they-were-cshtml-files-without-changi